# Kotlin+SpringBoot [Iniciante] Não consigo criar metodo Post

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jvm

Eu nem queria recorrer ao Stack em um problema tão simples, mas já esta se arrastando a dias e consegui implementar o metodo GET com uma certa facilidade, estou aprendendo kotlin e java, não estou conseguindo implementar o metodo POST, já testei no POSTMAN o GET e retornou ok,  mas queria incluir o metodo POST para acrescentar "NOVOS LIVROS, AUTORES E EDITORAS", tentei varias sentenças, mas por ser iniciante estou muito perdido.

```
package com.example.blog

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*


data class Relatorio(
        val titulo: String,
        val autor: String,
        val serie: String
)


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bradesco")
class BradescoController {


    @GetMapping()
    public fun relatorio(): Relatorio {
        val result = Relatorio(
                "Bradesco Prime, O Comeco",
                "Luis Carlos",
                "Coletanea Bradesco"
        )
                return result
}
    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/bradesco")
    public fun relatorio2() {
        "titulo" = "A historia de Luis Carlos"
        return "Atualizado";


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) é uma anotação usada para definir uma URL que vai ser solicitada:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public fun foo() {
    return "Foo";
}
```

você está criando a URL: **/foo**

A anotação em questão quando aplicada em nível de classe (quando colocada acima da classe controladora) não é necessária, porém ao ser colocada ela transforma todos seus métodos em URLs relativas.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bar")
class BarController{
    @PostMapping("/foo")
    public fun foo() {
        return "Foo";
    }
```

Neste caso você está criando uma URL **/foo** no caminho relativo de **/bar**

Logo seu POST fica com o caminho: **/bar/foo**

Vale lembrar que o @PostMapping é uma maneira mais simples de implementar o @RequestMapping no método POST.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @Brenno Serrato, se você quer utilizar um POST para acrescentar novos livros, eventualmente você vai precisar receber esse livro que precisa acrescentar no Body da sua requisição.

Isso pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
class BookController(private val bookService: BookService) {

    @PostMapping
    fun save(@RequestBody book: Book): Book {
        return bookService.save(book);
    }

}
```